# can't echo topics on the host computer with ros2 Docker

Tags: ros2, docker

I'm using [micros-ros](https://github.com/micro-ROS/docker/tree/iron) on my custom stm32f722 board connected through USB to a Jetson Nano, with ubuntu 22.04 (custom image for the nano) and ros2 iron. If I run:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=host --device=/dev/ttyACM0 microros/micro-ros-agent:iron serial --dev /dev/ttyACM0
```

then I can list and suscribe to micro-ros topics on the host computer. Moreover, I have a win11 computer on the same LAN running WSL (on a host network configuration, that is, sharing the same physical ethernet adapter) and Ubuntu22.04 and I can list and suscribe micro-ros topics there too. That is the expected behavior.
Now I want to replicate the same with a ublox GPS using [Kumar](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox) driver. So I make this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ros:iron

RUN mkdir -p /ublox_ws/src
WORKDIR /ublox_ws

RUN git -C src clone -b ros2 https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox.git
COPY f9p.launch.py src/ublox/ublox_gps/launch
COPY zed_f9p.yaml src/ublox/ublox_gps/config

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y python3-pip ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rmw-fastrtps-cpp \
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh \
    && rosdep update \
    && rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y \
    && colcon build \
    && rm -rf log/ build/ src/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ros_entrypoint.sh /

ENV RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp

# RUN echo ". /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
# RUN echo ". /ublox_ws/install/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

ENTRYPOINT ["/ros_entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

I build it with `docker build . -t ublox_gps` and running it with `docker run -it --rm --net=host --device=/dev/ttyACM1 ublox_gps:latest`
Inside the container I run `ros2 launch ublox_gps f9p.launch.py`
Doing that I can list the topics on the host computer and on WSL. But WSL is the only one that can suscribe and received messages from the Docker container. echoing the topics on the host computer doesn't get any message.

am I missing something? I'm wondering why one docker image is working ok and why the other not.

EDIT: I manage to isolate the line that makes it works on micro-ros-agent and it's the one related to https://github.com/micro-ROS/docker/blob/iron/micro-ROS-Agent/disable_fastdds_shm.xml
Adding that file and setting ENV makes that host computer can echo docker topics.

Thanks